# NPE when @Inject @Stateless service in a JAX-RS class in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jboss, ejb, jax-rs, jboss-eap-6

I've got that JAX-RS webservice:

```java
@Path("/my")
public class MyWS {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void save(SaveParam saveParam) {
        myService.save(saveParam);
    }
}
```

and that `@Stateless` service:

```java
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @TransactionAttribute
    public void save(SaveParam saveParam) {
        entityManager.persist(saveParam);
    }
}
```

Using JBoss EAP 6.2, myService is always `null` (not injected) when arriving in the `save` method.

I've tried to add `@ApplicationScoped` to `MyWS` class, but the same behavior is happening (`NullPointerException`). The only solution is to declare `MyWS` also as `@Stateless`, but that's not really have any sens, have it?

Is this a bug in JBoss EAP?

All my classes are in the same `war` project and I have a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` using CDI 1.0 spec. I also have a class extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and declaring the `@ApplicationPath`.

Comment: _"but that's not really have any sens"_ - That's actually how it's shown to be done in the [official EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm#GKNCY)

Comment: Good point, but there is also written: _JAX-RS and CDI have slightly different component models. By default, JAX-RS root resource classes are managed in the request scope, and no annotations are required for specifying the scope. CDI managed beans annotated with `@RequestScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` can be converted to JAX-RS resource classes._

Comment: See [Resteasy support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/CDI.html). I think it requires an extra module to be configured/added. I might be wrong. It also states it should be supported out the box (I guess meaning that the module is pre configure/loaded/whatever)

Comment: Maybe the warning has something to with it. Note this is is the JAX-RS 3.0.9 documentation. You should look for the 2.3.7, as that's what EAP uses (I believe). Actually, [here it is](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#CDI), but it pretty much states the same thing

Comment: Yes but normally, that's JBoss responsibility to integrate Resteasy correctly with CDI, and that's actually working... except without `@Stateless` on JAX-RS services obviously... so this would be a JBoss bug?

Comment: I think what's stated in the warning may be the problem. Not sure.

Comment: Created a bug report on JBossAS : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-110

Comment: i guess it is not only your service that  is null but also EntityManger is null .  Also try adding the unit name.         @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyDatasource")    EntityManager entityManager;

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a bug if you configure your REST service in web.xml. 
I have the same issue and i was getting crazy about this.
Just clean up the web.xml and it should not have anything related to REST.
@ApplicationPath is good enough for all REST setup.